# ¿Porque tengo esta excepcion "FileUriExposedException" cuando comparto imagenes con intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, excepciones, uri, sdk

En versiones inferiores a Android 8.0 no tengo problemas cuando uso el intent, pero cuando mi aplicación se ejecuta en un smartphone con android 8.0, entonces obtengo esta excepcion.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.propiedades.inmo.inmoob, PID: 14883
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///file%3A/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20191116_064343.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10216)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10222)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1667)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
    at com.propiedades.inmo.inmoob.adapters.InmuebleAdaptador$ViewHolder.onClick(InmuebleAdaptador.java:228)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

La parte de mi codigo que se encarga de compartir las imagenes a traves de un intent es el siguiente:

```
ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++){
     Uri uriImage = Uri.parse(imagenes[i]);

     files.add(uriImage);
}

intentCompartir.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);
intentCompartir.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
intentCompartir.putParcelableArrayListExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,files);
intentCompartir.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity (Intent.createChooser(intentCompartir,"Compartir via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**El error es generado por cuestiones de seguridad, actualmente si tu proyecto define como mínimo `targetSdkVersion = 24`, se debe hacer uso ahora de la clase [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) para acceder a un archivo o directorio.**

Recuerda también que es necesario el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE para que puedas acceder al archivo desde tu aplicación.

Ejemplo:

### [FileProvider, como acceder a un archivo.](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-FileProvider)

Crear el archivo `/res/xml/provider_paths.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

Define dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` el archivo y el permiso relacionado al paquete de tu aplicación:

```
<provider
    android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
    android:authorities="<Paquete aplicacion>.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Esta sería la forma a cargar el archivo suponiendo tener una archivo test.pdf localizado en `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/Data/"`:

```
   //Path directory of the file we want to load.
    File documentsPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/Data/");
    //If documentsPath doesn´t exists, then create
    if (!documentsPath.exists()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "create path: " + documentsPath);
        documentsPath.mkdir();
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "path: " + documentsPath + " exists!");
    }
    File file = new File(documentsPath, "test.pdf");

    if(file.exists()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "The file exists!, share file.");
        shareFile(file);
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "The file doesn´t exists!");
    }


    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

    Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("application/pdf")
            .setStream(uri)
            .setChooserTitle("Choose bar")
            .createChooserIntent()
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivity(intent);
```

Si deseas un ejemplo completo, lo puedes [ver aquí](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-FileProvider).

Comment: veo que usas ShareCompat en una activity, pero yo estoy intentando hacerlo desde un Adapter

Comment: @AbisurDiazRamirez en ese caso usa el Intent de tu pregunta que también es válido.

Comment: Al implementarlo obtengo esta excepción "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority"

Comment: Estoy implementandolo de la siguiente manera "File file = null;
                            file = new File(imagenes[i]);
                            Uri uriImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,context.getPackageName()+"fileprovider",file);"

Comment: @AbisurDiazRamirez en tu bloque <provider debes definir en android:authorities=" el paquete de tu app :

Comment: android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" ¿Asi no esta bien definido?

Comment: @AbisurDiazRamirez  si, excelente,  pero sería provider al final android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"

Comment: ya lo corregi, pero ahora tengo esta nueva excepcion "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20191116_064343.jpg"